# Colocando caixas explicativas dentro da administração do WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Gostaria de auxiliar os usuários do sistema colocando uma caixa com um texto explicativo dentro de cada parte da administração do WordPress, por exemplo em ***posts***, ***páginas*** e até em ***custom post types***.

Alguém conhece uma solução em plugin ou em functions que possa me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Marcos, só uma observação: please, please, não use formatação de código para dar destaque. É legal ter um padrão no site pois facilita a leitura. Seria bom se pudesse fazer uma leitura rápida em [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084). Valeu!

Comment: Vdd bem lembrado `não fazer isso` caso não queira expressar programação. Vou melhorar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para essas páginas específicas que cita, o que procura é um [Meta Box](http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:add_meta_box). Tem que definir o post type, localização e prioridade:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_box_sopt_38791' );

function add_box_sopt_38791() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'sectionid',
        'Custom box',
        'inner_box_sopt_38791',
        'product',  // Tipo de post
        'side',     // Localização 
        'high'      // Prioridade
    );
}

function inner_box_sopt_38791( $post )
{
    ?>
    <h1>Help</h1>
    <?php
}
```

Vai aparecer nas telas de Produtos, novos ou existentes (`http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php` e `http://example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php`:

[image]

Para aplicar em vários post types:

```
foreach( array('post','page','product') as $cpt )
    add_meta_box( $argumentos ); // Usar $cpt no tipo de post
```

<sup><sub>Ver exemplo de Meta Box que salva informações: [Extracting a WooCommerce Attribute and Put it in Google Book Viewer Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26572665/1287812)</sub></sup>

Se a intenção for uma Help box em outras páginas, aí vai ter que fazer gambiarra com jQuery:

```
foreach( array('post.php', 'post-new.php', 'profile.php', 'settings.php' ) as $page )
    add_action( "admin_footer-$page", 'jquery_magica' );

function jquery_magica() {
    // imprimir mágica
}
```

Finalmente, pode usar um recurso padrão que são as Tabs de Ajuda que aparecem no topo de cada página:

- [`add_help_tab`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen/add_help_tab)
- [Better Admin Help Tabs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-admin-help-tabs/)